# Inequality proof involving series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I have a question which starts like this:

Show that for $n>m$ we have $S_m < S_n\leq S_m+\frac{1}{m}\frac{1}{m!}$

Where $S_n=\frac{1}{0!}+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+ ... +\frac{1}{n!}$

I have tried using induction on n but that doesn't work for me, can somebody just  point me in the right direction on how I can go about proving this.

thanks

Comment: I don't think you need induction. $S_m<S_n$ is trivial. Can't you just write out each term of $S_n$ and $S_m$ to prove $S_n\leq S_m+\frac{1}{m}\frac{1}{m!}$?

Answer (score 1):

The left hand side is trival as all summands are positive.
For the right hand side note that for $m<k\le n$ we have
$$ \frac1{k!}=\frac1{m!\cdot \underbrace{(m+1)\cdot\ldots\cdot k}_{k-m\text{ factors}}}\le \frac1{m!\cdot (m+1)^{k-m}}$$.
Then you can compare with the geometric series 
$$ \frac1{m!}\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac1{(m+1)^j}=\frac1{m!}\cdot\frac{1}{m}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

First note that the required bound is independent of $n$. So you won't need to use $n$ in an essential way. In the worst case, $n$ will be very large, so you might as well write down the infinite sum $S = \frac{1}{(m+1)!} + \frac{1}{(m+2)!} + \cdots$. You want to prove that we have $S \leq \frac{1}{m} \frac{1}{m!}$. To do this, compare the series $S$ with a convenient geometric series.